# Kotlin call function with parameter by using Any is xxx || Any is yyy not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

my variable passed into my class constructor can be either Fragment or AppCompactActivity, so I use the following code to check wther it's valid in Glide's .with function.

```
class XXXX(private val parent: Any)

if (parent is AppCompatActivity || parent is Fragment) {
            // Load User Avatar
            Glide.with(parent)
                .load(dataSet[position].user.avatar)
                .into(viewHolder.userAvatar)
        }
```

when I only use `parent is AppCompactActivity` or `parent is Fragement`, the code works just fine. However, when I use an `or` operator, it gives me the following errors:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
with(Activity) defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
with(android.app.Fragment) defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
with(Context) defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
with(View) defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
with(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment) defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
with(FragmentActivity) defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin is a static, strongly typed language, so it always requires to understand what is the type of an object and which function exactly is invoked. Well, this is only partially true, it supports virtual functions, but `Glide.with()` is overloaded, so it has to be resolved at compile time.

If you use `parent is AppCompactActivity` then the compiler is sure `parent` is `AppCompactActivity`, so when you invoke `Glide.with(parent)` it knows it has to use `Glide.with(FragmentActivity)`. Similarly, if you use `parent is Fragement` then it knows it has to invoke `Glide.with(Fragment)`.

If you use `parent is AppCompatActivity || parent is Fragment` then the compiler could assume parent is either `AppCompatActivity` or `Fragment`, but it still doesn't know, which `Glide.with()` function to use. This has to be decided at runtime, but the compiler has to resolve this call at compile time, which is not possible.

To fix the problem, you need to provide two separate control flow paths to use the proper `with()` function:

```kotlin
val glide = when (parent) {
    is AppCompatActivity -> Glide.with(parent)
    is Fragment -> Glide.with(parent)
    else -> ... // throw exception?
}
glide.load(dataSet[position].user.avatar)
    .into(viewHolder.userAvatar)
```

It looks like we execute exactly the same code for both cases, but in fact this is not true. If you ctrl+click on both `with()` functions, you'll see they point at different implementations.

If you do this often in your code, you can create an utility function:

```kotlin
fun test() {
    glideWith(parent)
        .load(dataSet[position].user.avatar)
        .into(viewHolder.userAvatar)
}

fun glideWith(context: Any) = when (context) {
    is AppCompatActivity -> Glide.with(parent)
    is Fragment -> Glide.with(parent)
    else -> ... // throw exception?
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of how kotlin works :). This solves your question so much!